# What's the algorithm to translate 8 byte memory into a double number on x86 32bit?

Tags: floating-point, x86, 32-bit

So basically I disassemble some code on 32bit Linux and in the rodata section, where double should exist, I find these 8 bytes:

```
00000000 00002440
```

The original double number is 10.0

Could anyone tell me how to transform this 8 bytes into double?

Comment: Those 8 bytes are double, what do you want to convert? If you want to convert from the decimal value string "10.0" into double then use try http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ or http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049048

Comment: @MitchWheat 10.0 is 0x4024000000000000 in binary. x86 is little endian so the stored bytes are reversed

Comment: I knew I'd regret saying that!! :)

Comment: I can see at least two interpretations of the question: 1. What code would be needed to turn the 8 bytes into a double in the program? 2. Why does this bit pattern represent 10.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bytes into a buffer and ask `C` to interpret the memory as a double.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(){
    char* foo = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x24\x40";
    double bar =*((double*) foo);
    printf("%f\n", bar);
}
```

Output:

```
10.000000
```