# How to translate this 8 bytes into assemblable double format in nasm?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, nasm

So basically I have some asm code disassembled from a ELF binary, on 32 bit Linux.

In the .rodata section, I can find a sequence of 8 byte like this:

```
00000000 00002440
```

I know it represent a double number (which is 10.0), and I am trying to re-use it in my nasm code like this:

```
a dq 00000000 00002440      ; how to adjust it?

fld    qword [a]
fstp   QWORD [esp+0x18]
fld    QWORD [esp+0x18]
fstp   QWORD [esp+0x4]
mov    DWORD [esp],b
call   printf
```

Obviously **a dq 00000000 00002440** is not correct, and I have tried for several ways, but still can not assemble it using follow command (or some times I can assemble, but just get a wrong result as 0.00)

```
nasm -f elf test.s
```

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the algorithm to translate 8 byte memory into a double number on x86 32bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098681/whats-the-algorithm-to-translate-8-byte-memory-into-a-double-number-on-x86-32bi)

Comment: @BruceDawson This question asks for a nasm code sequence, rather than an algorithm.

Comment: The leading zeros shouldn't be necessary. `a dq 2440h` (or 0x... if you prefer). Oh, wait! Is that original sequence of bytes little endian? Maybe `a dq 0424000000000000h`? Nasm will let you put underscores in a number (with no effect) if it helps you count zeros `a dq 0424_0000_0000_0000h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent.

```
dq 0x4024000000000000
dq 10.0
```

See [the manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) for details.